# No errors in Nuclide with Flow

Tags: react-native, atom-editor, nuclide-editor

I try to use Flow in my Nuclide installation but I can't see any diagnostics in my React-Native project. But running flow from cli results int 1000+ errors.

If I save a file the spinner in the bottom bar is spinning and then disappearing completely (no Idle).

**.flowconfig**

```
[ignore]

[include]

[libs]

[lints]

[options]
```

**package.json**

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
    "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.9.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.56.0",
    "jest": "19.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.2"
  },
```

**My App.js**

```
/* @flow */
Math.pow('X');
import boot from "./app/boot";
const app = boot();
export default app;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I too was experiencing frustrating issues with getting Nuclide Diagnostics to report Flow issues to show up in Atom.

Just as you mentioned, running Flow in the CLI would pick up errors, but nothing would show up in the IDE.

I came across your post a bit late, but here is what I did that (finally) did the trick.

1) Probably not necessary, though I did it anyway... I uninstalled Atom to the best of my ability following this post: https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-completely-uninstall-atom-for-mac/9084/42

2) I downloaded the latest version of Atom and installed it: https://atom.io/

3) I installed my linters first before installing Nuclide. **This seemed to be what I was missing from all my other attempts.** I ran `apm install linter`, `apm install linter-eslint`, and `apm install linter-flow`. I fired up Atom, allowed the IDE to install `linter-ui-default`, and then verified that Atom's own `linter-flow` was picking up Flow errors. Alas, it was! Good shape.

4) I then finally installed `nuclide`. When prompted with the choice of either disabling `linter` or `atom-ide-diagnostics-ui` to avoid duplicate linting issues, I chose to disable `atom-ide-diagnostics-ui` to verify that the IDE was still properly picking up Flow issues and fortunately, it was.

5) I then went and switched off `linter` and re-enabled `atom-ide-diagnostics` (Atom > Config > `nuclide` > `use` > `"atom-ide-diagnostics-ui": true`). To my huge surprise, everything was still linting and the Flow issues were now integrated into Atom using Nuclide's Diagnostic UI!

Here is a list of the packages I installed in pretty much chronological order:

`├── busy-signal@1.4.3
├── intentions@1.1.5
├── linter@2.2.0 (disabled)
├── linter-eslint@8.4.0
├── linter-flow@5.6.1
├── linter-ui-default@1.6.10
└── nuclide@0.271.0`

---

Edit: Added a screenshot of my Nuclide settings

### [image: Nuclide settings]

Good luck and I hope this helps some!

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer! It just helped me to fix showing flow error in my Atom.